# How to run a system file check on an external HD?

Tags: sfc

I have a hard drive plugged into a dock that has Windows 7 installed on it, I would like to do a SFC on it, because when I do it internally it says some files can't be repaired, what is the command?

Comment: Do you mean the `chkdsk` command?

Comment: @fixer1234 you can specify the correct partitions, I just can't remember the command.

Comment: @txtechhelp no I mean sfc

Comment: @TheX - I take it back.  sfc does have commandline arguments for using it offline or outside of Windows.  I had never used it that way.  See this link: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termss/p/sfc-command-system-file-checker.htm.  It is capable of doing what it does on a live system, so I suspect the results will be the same running it on an externally-connected drive.  You may need other tools to repair it.  Also check out this site: http://support2.microsoft.com/fixit/.  It is a Microsoft wizard-based fixit site for a broad range of problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AEisen Sep 8, 2010 at 3:08 AM 
>   I'm not sure about a Windows repair, but
>   a Windows Vista based OS (Vista, PE, 7, 2008) will be able to run
>   System Files Checker on an offline Windows directory.
>
> SFC /scannow /OFFWINDIR=remotedrive:\Windows /OFFBOOTDIR=remotedrive:
>
> Example:
>
> SFC /scannow /OFFWINDIR=F:\Windows /OFFBOOTDIR=F:\
>
> Following that, you can always run chkdsk /b on the drive once that
>   finishes (unless it's pre-Vista, in which case it's chkdsk /r)

See the answer listed here.

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/110283-is-it-possible-to-run-a-windows-repair-on-an-external-usb-drive-that-was-pulled